# Is Heisenberg Uncertainty related to symmetry breaking?

Tags: symmetry, quantum-field-theory

I am wondering if Heisenberg Uncertainty has a deep relationship to symmetry breaking. It seems that observation will break symmetry. If that is the case, how can I think of Heisenberg Uncertainty in terms of symmetry breaking? Does it just describe what will be observed under those conditions? Is it some kind of relationship between continuous and discrete symmetry? Or is it just incorrect to say symmetry breaks under observation.

I'm fresh into my studies on these things, so please correct any wrong assumptions on my part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be an interesting question. But I'm afraid that most people on this site don't know what "symmetry breaking" is. I for one am among these.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I think in QM symmetry breaking is usually taken to mean that there exist ground states which are not invariant under the action of the symmetry. This means that you can build a perturbation theory around this ground state which does not "see" the symmetry at all. If the ground state is unique symmetry breaking (in this sense) cannot happen.

Comment: In my opinion symmetry breaking has little (not to say nothing) to do with the uncertainty principle. With the above conventions symmetry breaking is a statement about a Hamiltonian, whereas the uncertainty principle can be interpreted as saying "observables don't commute". Classically, where everything commutes, discrete symmetries are broken rather often (consider a sinusoidal potential, if you have small energy you will be running around in one well and not see anything at all of the global symmetry).